# Show that $\cup _{n=1,2,3,...} (-1+1/n,0)=(-1,0)$.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

My proof. Initially, we will show that $\cup _{n=1,2,3,...} (-1+1/n,0)\subseteq (-1,1)$. For every $n=1,2,3,...$ sicnce $-1<-1+1/n<1-1/n<1$, $(-1+1/n,1-1/n)\subseteq (-1,1)$.

Now, we will show vice versa. Let $x\in (-1,1)$. Then, $-1<x<1$. So, $(1-x)>0$. Then, by the Archimedian property, there is a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $n(1-x)>1$. Thus, $-1<x<1-1/n$. i.e., $x\in(-1+1/n,1-1/n)$. It was prove.

**Can you check my proof?**

Comment: Do you mean $\bigcup_{n=1,2,3,\dots} \left(-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)=(-1,1)$?

Comment: Obviously false as stated. The lhs does not contain any points in $(0,1)$.

Comment: @kccu Yes. Is there a problem?

Comment: @Kahler The title and body of your question both say $\left(-1+\frac{1}{n},0\right)$, not $\left(-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$.

Comment: @kccu edited...

Answer (score 0):

The forward implication is correct, though if you wanted to add more detail you could start with "let $x \in \bigcup_{n=1,2,3,\dots}\left(-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$. Then $x \in \left(-1+\frac{1}{n},1-\frac{1}{n}\right)$ for some $n\in \mathbb{N}$..." and proceed to show $x \in (-1,1)$.

For the reverse implication, you showed $x<1-\frac{1}{n}$, but not $x>-1+\frac{1}{n}$. You also need to use the fact that $1+x>0$, so there exists $m\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m(1+x)>1$. Then $x>-1+\frac{1}{m}$. Now take $N$ to be the larger of $n$ and $m$ and show $x \in \left(-1+\frac{1}{N},1-\frac{1}{N}\right)$.